# my while loop skips an if statement and goes straight to the else statement

Tags: python, while-loop, scope

I have a while loop that seems to be skipping my first if statement and moving straight to the else statement. I've triple checked the code and it seems to be correct but it still wont acknowledge my first if statement. (There is a lot of code in the program not included in this question)

I've tried moving the else statement to different indices as well as reconfiguring the `initialize_objects()` function to return the master list instead of None. None of which seem to do anything because I do not receive an error, it just runs the else statement at the bottom no matter what.

```
def initialize_objects():
        global jackson_checking, jackson_savings, jackson_business, master_list



        jackson_checking = CheckingAccount('Jackson', 4100)
        jackson_savings = SavingsAccount('Jackson', 100000)
        jackson_business = BusinessAccount('Jackson', 15000)


        master_list = [[jackson_checking, 1, 1], [jackson_savings, 1, 2], [jackson_business, 1, 3]]


        return None

    initialize_objects()

    while isSessionOn is True:
        print('Welcome to 24-hour ATM service.')
        print('insert your card.')


        # Card reading the customer info representation
        customerID = input('Enter your customer id number: ')
        print("\n")


        cust_accounts = []
        for i in master_list:
            if i[1] == customerID:
                cust_accounts.append(i[2])
                isCustomer = True 

        if isCustomer is True:
            isAccountSelected = False


        else:
            print("cannot find your record.")
            print("Please get your card.")
            print("Closing this session...")
```

What I am expecting to happen is `if customerID == 1`, then the program should move on to another while loop that is below isAccountSelected (not included in this question). What happens instead is when I enter 1 as the input for customerID, it moves straight to the else statement at the bottom and just continues to ask for another CustomerID...

it looks like this:

```
Welcome to 24-hour ATM service.
insert your card.
Enter your customer id number: 1


cannot find your record.
Please get your card.
Closing this session...
Welcome to 24-hour ATM service.
insert your card.
Enter your customer id number: 1


cannot find your record.
Please get your card.
Closing this session...
Welcome to 24-hour ATM service.
insert your card.
Enter your customer id number:
```

Comment: As a matter of habit, you should not use `is True`, just use `== True`. You only want to use `is` in specific circumstances.

Comment: python input returns string, but you want to compare it with integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `input` in Python always returns a string. So when the user types in `1` as their ID, the Python program actually makes `customerID` the string `"1"`. So when you try to compare `1=="1"`, it always fails and it always goes to the `else` block.

Comment: I think this is only true in Python 3, but this is likely the problem